# Passing User_Fields to Contact form 7

Tags: functions, plugin-contact-form-7

I'm trying to pass some custom field data to contact form 7 - The billing address and name and email address.

I've created a function that pulls in these details from the database - is there an easy way I can send these details in an email when a forms sent?

Can I possible somehow pass the data to the form sending template.

Here is my function that pulls in the correct data.

```
function rinfo() {

if ( is_user_logged_in() ) {
    global $current_user;
    get_currentuserinfo();

      echo 'Username: ' . $current_user->user_login . "\n";
      echo 'User email: ' . $current_user->user_email . "\n";
      echo 'Address: ' . $current_user->shipping_address_1 . "\n";
}

}
```

Comment: You'll want to use the `wpcf7_before-send_mail` hook to access and inject your data. You can read [This Article](http://xaviesteve.com/3298/wordpress-contact-form-7-hook-unofficial-developer-documentation-and-examples/) for more information, hope it helps!

Comment: I'll look into that hook @Howdy_McGee

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This plugin helped me solve my question - It pulls in all types of data you just pass the correct key search for "Contact Form 7 Dynamic Text Extension" in the plugin section.